# Make label near the plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my data and code with function `geom_text_repel` in case of the overlapping:

```
            player2    fgper       pts        mp
1        Dan Dickau 39.34739  5.816667 15.393333
2       Danny Ainge 45.64634 12.305895 28.008899
3      Daniel Ewing 37.89910  3.255639 12.684211
4  Dante Cunningham 45.50715  5.965135 21.207607
5     Joe Alexander 36.99286  4.208955 11.119403
6   Jordan Crawford 29.15000  4.500000 11.500000
7       Joe Crispin 36.71111  3.761905  7.428571
8        Joe Dumars 44.50372 16.064602 34.723009
9        Joe Binion 43.75000  1.272727  4.636364
10     Joe Courtney 45.71220  2.750000  7.802083


ggplot(data=data_agg,aes(x=pts,y=fgper,color=mp)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = player_dum),segment.colour = NA,box.padding = 0.2) + 
  theme(legend.key.height = unit(2.5,"cm")) + scale_color_gradientn(colors=rainbow(4))
```

The output is as follows:
[image]

The problem is that Patrick Ewing is in fact the point(20,50), then its position is far from the supposedly labelled point.

However, the example shown by the package `ggrepel` could draw the plot as follows:

[image]

And its code is :

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars,
            aes(wt, mpg, colour = factor(cyl))) +
    geom_point()
 p + geom_text_repel(aes(label=rownames(mtcars)))
```

It does not seem a lot different than mine, so what should I do to make the label near the point itself, at least people who see know that the label is indicating a point nearby.

Any idea would be helpful!

Comment: It would be helpful if you didn't turn off the segment. Smaller padding also helps, perhaps use `point.padding = NA` .

Comment: There's a lot, perhaps too much, going on in the graph.  Would it work to take out mp and use a single color for the points that are labeled, so they stand out better?